# Comparing significance of two tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have read a [2011 article in Nature Neuroscience](https://doi.org/10.1038/nn.2886) (let's call it Meta-Study A) which, if correct, seems to be at odds with my understanding of hypothesis testing. Meta-Study A is a meta-study of hypothesis testing in neuroscience. In order to explain the main point of Meta-Study A, I will now present one of the publications that is examined in Meta-Study A. I will call that publication Study B.

In Study B the authors measure the variable "fraction of active neurons" in mice of 4 different categories: mutant vs control mice, and naive mice vs mice trained in a certain task (expert mice). A significance test (e.g. MannWhitneyU) is performed for naive vs expert condition. It is found that the difference is significant in the mutant case (pval < 0.05), and not significant in the control case (pval > 0.05). The authors of Study B have summarized this finding as follows: "The percentage of neurons showing cue-related activity (significantly) increased with training in the mutant mice (P < 0.05), but not in the control mice (P > 0.05)".

According to the authors of Meta-Study A, the above claim the authors of Study B made was too strong and not justified by the performed tests. Namely, the argument in Meta-Study A is that if in one case the pval=0.049 and in another pval=0.051, it is not justified to claim that the former effect is stronger than the latter.

**Question 1:** Do you believe that this argument is correct? Is it not allowed/misleading to say that one number is larger than another, even if the difference is as small as 0.051 > 0.049?

Now, I would like to focus on the actual point of Meta-Study A, namely demonstrating that one effect (e.g. learning-related changes in mutant mice) is significantly larger than another (e.g. task-related changes in controls). I agree with the authors of Meta-Study A that the authors of Study B did not show this. But how to test this? In Meta-Study A (Fig 1a and 1d) they suggest subtracting the variable of interest between naive and expert mice, and then testing the difference between mutants and controls. On the first glance, this seems like a reasonable approach. But I think it is actually very wrong. What if mutants have on average 100x times more active neurons than controls, regardless of the other parameter. Then the difference in mutants would always be larger simply because it is measured on another scale. Would you agree that this approach is flawed, or am I missing something? I considered normalizing as a solution, but I am not sure it is fair, or even what exactly to normalize to.

**Question 2**: How to correctly test if one effect is significantly larger than another? Is it possible to directly compare p-values given the number of samples in each case? Or maybe some permutation test?

P.S. I am aware of multiple testing, namely that all p-value thresholds should be Bonferroni-corrected. I omitted this part for simplicity because it is orthogonal to the main point of the question.

**Edit 1**: As requested, I will provide a bit more details about the experiments themselves. A typical study with mice involves 10-20 mice, which are trained over multiple days (e.g. two weeks), once per day. Each training session involves multiple trials (typically ~100 per day). Mice learn the task by trying, and thus become expert at it towards the end of the study. Thus, such studies are interested in comparing sessions where performance of a given mouse is very high (expert) to the sessions where it is at chance level (naive). In this case, the test is not paired, as mice do a different number of trials in each session, and there is no direct link between sessions on different days. However, there are other studies which involve paired tests, for example, pre vs post-reward activity over trials. It would be great to be able to understand how to perform comparison of significance of two effects in paired and unpaired cases.

Comment: please clarify what is  study A  and study B ?

Comment: @SubhashC.Davar It is written in the text. Study A is a meta-study of hypothesis testing in neuroscience (see attached link). Study B is one publication that has been presented as an example in Study A, and the details of which I have described.

Comment: If you want us to look at a table in a publication it seems reasonable to reproduce at least the key parts of it in your question, rather than showing an link and expecting us to find the table. Sometimes I am willing to take a look, but in this case, I would have to give up personal information to get behind the wall to look at the publication. // Also, there is an advantage to a clear exposition of the main question, perhaps leaving (irresistible?) side issues to notes at the end.

Comment: Question 2 How to correctly test if one effect is significantly larger than another? Is it possible to directly compare p-values given the number of samples in each case? Or maybe some permutation test? - This question is inapproprate and confusing.

Comment: @BruceET I'm not sure I follow. I reproduced a summary of the first page of the publication in my question. I have made a reference to figure 1. To the best of my understanding, the publication is in open access, what do you mean by going behind the wall? What else do you want? Could you also be a bit more clear about your second point? Would you like me to shorten the text to a minimum?

Comment: @SubhashC.Davar What do you mean by "inapproprate and confusing". Does this question offend you in some way?? Please be constructive and precise about your criticism, otherwise I cannot improve the question.

Comment: @SubhashC.Davar I agree that magnitude is not quite the correct word. Can you suggest a better word? Is the statement "significance of one effect is more significant than the significance of another effect" better undertandable?

Comment: continued   Your question does not offend me. It seems to convey as if p- values represent the size (magnitude) of effect. Or may be some permutation test? You do not disclose which test you want to compare it with. The convex statements do make your final query inappropriate. You may revise the statements if you are convinced. It is your prerogative. thanks for your views.

Comment: @SubhashC.Davar Question 2 is a very general question on whether it is possible to compare the significance of effects between two arbitrary tests, preferably in a non-parametric way. I am not sure what is wrong with this question. Could you please clarify? Also, I am unfamiliar with the expression "convex statement", can you please clarify what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all four categories of mice are disjoint (Mutant vs Ordinary, Expert vs Naive, leads to ME, MN, OE, ON) so that all tests are two-sample tests. In that case,
it is difficult to know how differences $D_m = ME-MN$ and $D_o = OE - ON.$ are found.
[Your say, "[T]hey suggest subtracting the variable of interest between naive and expert mice." What is of interest and what is being subtracted?] Does an N-mouse 'graduate' to being an E-mouse during the experiment?

Ideally, we might look at a two-way ANOVA with factors Genetics (with levels M and O) and
Practice (N and E). Then one could look at G by P interaction and perhaps resolve some
of the issues you raise. However, you mention a Wilcoxon test, so I guess someone
has decided data are not normal. Some sort of permutation test might be possible,
but it is not clear what the metric would be or exactly what would be permuted.

At one point you mention mice performing 'tasks'. How many tasks altogether for each mouse. Are the tasks the same and given in the same sequence to all four
categories of mice? And is the answer the same for both Studies A and B? To the extent that there is pairing,, by task that raises the possibility of paired tests, and
thus the possibility of resolving some of the issues you raise.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you suggested, I have done my best to read through and clarify the question. Indeed, I agree with you that it is not clear how subtraction is done, especially if the conditions are disjoint. I do not understand that part of the Meta-Study A. Regardless, the most important question is Question 2, that is, how to correctly compare if one effect is more significant than another.

Indeed, data from such tests is frequently non-normal. It would be great to be able to do this in a non-parametric way. I agree, main problem is not knowing what is a good null hypothesis

Comment: Let's say I have performed two completely unrelated MannWhitneyU tests. Can I make a "meta-test" to compare if one of them is significantly more confident than the other?